# How to use mpfr/gmp in Qt-Creator properly?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, mpfr

Hello I want to create a Qt5 project using Qt-creator and want to use mpfr/gmp so I need how to configure the project.

because if i compile I get these errors:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <mpfr.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    mpfr_t x, y, z, t;
    mpfr_inits2 (256, x, y, z, t, (mpfr_ptr) 0);

    return a.exec();
}
```

The output:

```
 error: undefined reference to `mpfr_inits2'
```

But on codeblocks I add the include path and library path and add the flags `-lgmp -lmpfr` to the compiler and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In QtCreator, open the `.pro` file of your project and append the following line:

```
unix: LIBS += -lmpfr -lgmp
```

Alternatively, you can also use the UI to do this: In the "Projects" list, right-click on your project, select "Add library" > "System Library". In the "Library file" field add e.g. `/usr/lib/mpfr.so`. QtCreator will then turn this into `-lmpfr`, as shown in the "Summary" view. Repeat these steps to add `/usr/lib/libgmp.so` as well.

[image]
[image]